# Dotnetnuke (DNN) SMTP setup failing?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Just recently, without intervention, the SMTP settings for a clients DNN install is failing. I can log into her gmail account fine, but setting up the SMTP in DNN gives an error:

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Im using smtp.gmail.com:587 and using SSL connection... still get the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuens out to be a google apps setting to allow less secure apps to use Gmail.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

SMTP Settings for my DNN sites using Google for SMTP

Server and Port: smtp.gmail.com:587

Connection Limit: 1

SMTP Authentication: Basic

SSL: Enabled

Username: emailaddresshere

Password: passwordhere